# D3. What x,y coordinate of an element in a hierarchy with respect to the parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, svg

I have an `svg` hierarchy that is schematically as follow:

[image]

For the `group` element with id *combined* what is its x,y coordinate with respect to parent `svg` element? Is there a generalized way to compare/add/subtract `svg` element coordinates?

Comment: You can use `.getBBox()` on the element.

Comment: Thanks so much Lars.